# Can't add my material with geometry nodes?

Tags: materials, geometry-nodes

So I am using Blender 3.1 and I am trying to add a rocky ground texture –that I got from 3D textures.com (https://3dtextures.me/2022/02/07/ground-dirt-009/)– to an object with geometry nodes. I am currently following this tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o2OPzAScThg&t=48s), but whenever I add the material in the set material node just like in the video, the texture doesn't show up on my object. It just gets slightly darker.

I tried to add the material to the object in the materials tab, but that also doesn't work.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: You're in material preview mode - go into rendered preview, it should have color.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that the material you're using, although not shown, is using a UV Map as its texture coordinates.  Switch that to generated as in the below material screenshot and it will work.  Generated geometry in Geometry Nodes doesn't have a UV Map by default.  (It may have been different in 3.0Alpha. A lot changed before the 3.0 release.)

[image]